# @Query with Pageable parameter in spring-data-couchbase

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to add my own (custom) findMembersByName method to my couchbase repository.

My code looks like this:

```
public interface MembersRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Member, Long>, MembersRepositoryCustom {
    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE (IFMISSING(firstname,'') || ' ' || IFMISSING(lastname,'')) LIKE $1 AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    Page<Member> findMembersByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

but if I try run this method I get exception:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParameterOutOfBoundsException: Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!
```

All works fine if I remove pagination, so my query is fine.
There is a problem with passing 'name' argument to statement.

How should I pass additional param to query when I use pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page/Slice queries don't make much sense with inlined N1QL queries.

That is because by definition each new page must use a slightly modified query (limiting and offsetting on the current page). This is not something we support with a plain String statement.

(note: However this particular message may still be from a bug in `Spring Data Commons`)

Comment: But in documentation is example where inlined N1QL query is used with Pageable - Paragraph 5.4.6. : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/

Comment: paragraph 5 is an include of the general-purpose common documentation, all Spring Data modules have it but it uses JPA as the examples' module. In Spring Data Couchbase for now I'm just not confident enough that I can safely mutate the inlined query and support pageable with such queries.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: the bug that you came across (not root cause) was fixed :) https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-804

Comment: In Spring Data JPA, they handle this problem with an optional [`countQuery`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#countQuery--) provided separately. Couldn't you do something similar? (with a `#n1ql.paging` placeholder in the custom query to inject the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` values)